# query space of TDengine Cluster

Tags: tdengine

I have built a tdengine cluster with three nodes. And want to the space that the cluster used. Are there any commands or sqls that can help me check how much space I have used? Just like hdfs using a command like

`hadoop fs -du -h /warehouse/hive/warehouse/`

using which I can get the space info for every path or an individual file.
or any sqls like

```
select segment_name, bytes from user_segments where segment_type = 'TABLE'; 

Select Tablespace_Name,Sum(bytes)/1024/1024 From Dba_Segments Group By Tablespace_Name；
```

these ORACLE sqls will return the physical space allocated to an individual table or the usage situation of the tablespace.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
select last(disk_used,disk_total) from log.dn group by fqdn;
```